# How to call a 3rd party API from a controller? Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, api, rest-api

I built a custom module. Its admin tables with CRUD functionality. I am putting a new button on the grid via the Ui_component listing XML file. When this button gets clicked I want to call a 3rd party API to load data into the current table.

This is the code for the button:

```
<item name="refresh" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">refresh</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/refreshAction</item>
        </item>
```

The refraction controller is where I need help with the code to make the API call. For now, I just want to echo out the response, once I get the API call to return a successful response I will deal with actually saving the data to the table.
The code I have now that's returning a 500 internal server error looks like this:

```
public function execute()
{
 $this->_curl->get('https://online.jil.com/api/index.aspx?action=GetAllDIDs');
    $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
    echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I call Google Map API for get Latitude and Longitute of the specific location parameter

I used this code in controller

```
public function execute()
{
    $url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%27White+House,+Pennsylvania+Avenue+Northwest,+Washington,+DC,+United+States%27&sensor=true_or_false&key=AIzaSyA28OnwaqgoNtdbtCBAvfD6wUJnvzBrroE";

    $geocodeFromAddr = file_get_contents($url);

    $output = json_decode($geocodeFromAddr);

    print_r($output);
}
```

**Note: API Key is generated for Specific Domain**

***I Hope This Helps You***

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't provide a centralize way to make api REST call to external services.
I worked with lot of customers and developers always use their own REST implementation, using multiple libraries like Guzzle, Curl, Zend...

That's why I recommand you to use this module to industialize your REST API call through Guzzle library: https://github.com/zepgram/module-rest